# filter ftp log file in ftp server

Tags: linux, ftp

In the ftp server, it has a large log file to record when users download data from server.
the log file items like

```
Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12461] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:13 2012 [pid 12460] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon     password "gxxglxxxxt@google.com"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:14 2012 [pid 12462] [ftp] OK DOWNLOAD: Client "66.249.68.236",   "/pub/10.5524/100001_101000/100022/readme.txt", 451 bytes, 1.39Kbyte/sec
Sat Jun  2 03:32:22 2012 [pid 12677] CONNECT: Client "66.249.68.236"
Sat Jun  2 03:32:23 2012 [pid 12676] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "66.249.68.236", anon password "xxxxxbot@google.com"
Sat Jun  2 03:35:27 2012 [pid 12706] [ftp] FAIL DOWNLOAD: Client "66.2
```

So how can i get a simple log file only contain records in latest one week or 7 days

Thanks

Comment: You can manually prepare this log file with `grep` with `awk`/`sed` utilities. Also you can write simple Python/Perl/Ruby/etc script for collect data with regular expressions.